# Same line colors on sns.lineplot

Tags: pandas, plot, seaborn, line-plot

I have a task, trying to draw `plot` where x is year and y is the value of games, released this year. Also, I have information about game platforms. So I want to draw 10 different lines of 10 different colors. I need to do it via for cycle. If I draw it without hue param - lines have different colors, but if I add it, all lines become blue.
Code is on screenshot via the link.
[image: Code]

```py
for platform in top10_platofrm_sales_dict:  
    sns.lineplot(
        data=pivot_top_10
        .query('platform == @platform and year_of_release !=0 '),
        x='year_of_release',
        y='name',
        hue = 'platform'
    )
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(16, 8)
```

Comment: What is the problem with not using a loop and using `hue=` instead?

Comment: as Diziet suggests, the problem is the loop itself. I suspect each `sns.lineplot` is adding a new line object separate from the previous lines so that the color cycling starts over at blue. If you remove the loop, adjust your query to just `year_of_release != 0` then you should get a set of lines colored by `platform`.